# LeetCode question number: 189 Rotate Array, showing Run Time error, why?

Tags: arrays

```
class Solution {
public:
void rotate(vector<int>& nums,int low,int high)
{
    high=high-1;
    while(low<high)
    {
      swap(nums[low],nums[high]);
      low++;
      high--;
    }
}

void rotate(vector<int>& nums, int k) 
 {
    int n=nums.size();
    if(n<k)
    {

    }
    else
    {
      rotate(nums,n-k,n);
      rotate(nums,0,n-k);
      rotate(nums,0,n);
    }
  
     
 }
};
```

(https://leetcode.com/problems/rotate-array/submissions/1047906503/?source=submission-noac)

i tried to run on the above code on sample test cases and it passed the sample test cases.
But when i tried to submit the above code i got the below error:

```
Line 1034: Char 34: runtime error: addition of unsigned offset to 0x602000000350 overflowed to 0x60200000034c (stl_vector.h)
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:1043:34
```

can anyone explain me why my code is not working on all test cases and why i am getting this error ?

Comment: THe link doesn't work for unregistered users

Comment: I can't see the problem definition. But imagine what happens if you call `rotate(v, -3)` (if that's allowed)